Can you tell me what part of speech "use" is here?
I need help.
The word "use" in the sentence "Avoiding drug use" is confusing me
Can you tell me what part of speech "use" is here?

It's a noun. Compare The use of drugs is increasing, where you can tell from the initial definite article that whatever follows must be a noun. In your context, drug is a "noun adjunct" (a noun used before another noun as an adjective).

Use noun /yus/  [uncountable, singular] the act of using something; the state of being used A ban was imposed on the use of chemical weapons. The software is designed for use in schools. I'm not sure that this is the most valuable use of my time. The chapel was built in the 18th century and is still in use today. The pool is for the use of members only. Oxford Learner's Dictionaries

As @MichaelHarvey points out, the noun use has an s (unvoiced) sound, so it rhymes with juice and with the adjective loose. The verb use on the other hand has a z (voiced) sound, so it whymes with Jews and choose and the verb lose.

@MichaelHarvey, use also has many count uses.

@PaulTanenbaum - a piece of string has many uses. On the same Oxford Learner's page - [countable, uncountable] a purpose for which something is used; a way in which something is or can be used I'm sure you'll think of a use for it. This chemical has a wide range of industrial uses.

But "Avoiding drug use" isn't actually a sentence anyway- it's a (participle-based) noun phrase (equivalent to the avoidance of drug use), that might be used as a title.

Might also be worth noting that the verb "use" and the noun "use" are homographs; they're spelt the same but have different pronunciations.  The verb is /juz/ but the noun is pronounced /jus/.

In "avoid drug use", 'drug use' is a compound noun which means the use of drugs.
It essentially means the same as:

Avoid using drugs (where 'using' is a verb)
Avoid the use of drugs (where 'the use of drugs' is a longer compound noun)


Use in drug use is a noun.  LDOCE has an example  sentence almost right at the back, under COLLOCATIONS, just after sense 17 of the section use2 /juːs/ ●●● S1 W1 noun:

drug/alcohol use


Drug use among teenage boys is on the increase.

